# List all files that end in a set of characters in all subdirectories that don't end in the set of characters

Tags: files, ls

How would you list files that end in **x, y or z** in sub directories that DO NOT END in **x,y or z**?

Comment: `echo *[^xyz]/*[xyz]`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working as it's only returning "*[^xyz]/*[xyz]"

Comment: can you please provide us your directory structure ?

Comment: well it would apply to all the sub directories in the directory that is specified regardless of the structure

Answer (score 2):

To avoid descending in `*[xyz]` at all, and for regular files at depth 2 (that is find `a/x`, but not `ax/x` nor `a/b` nor `x` and doesn't look beyond two directories like `a/b/x`), POSIXly:

```
LC_ALL=C find . \( ! -name '*[xyz]' -o -prune \) \
  -path './*/*' -prune -type f -name '*[xyz]'
```

That would be the equivalent of:

```
printf '%s\n' *[!xzy]/*[xyz]
```

Except that it would also look inside hidden dirs and for hidden files and would not look into symlinks to directories and only look for regular files.

If you want to look for `*[xyz]` regular files at any depth provided their *direct* parent directory does not end in `xyz` (so would find `x`, `a/x`, `a/b/x`, `x/b/x`, but not `x/x` nor `a/x/x`), with GNU `find`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -regex '.*[^xyz]/[^/]*[xyz]' -type f
```

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extended_glob
printf '%s\n' **/*[xzy]~*[xyz]/[^/]#(D.)
```

POSIXly:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[xzy]' -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    case ${f%/*} in
      *[xzy]) ;;
      *) printf '%s\n' "$f"
    esac
  done' sh {} +
```

If you don't want for look inside `*[xyz]` at all, even in subdirs, (that is if you don't want to find `x/a/x`) then that's just:

```
find . -name '*[xyz]' -prune -type f
```

`-prune` tells `find` not to descend into the directory (and returns true).

Or with `zsh`:

```
setopt extended_glob
printf '%s\n' (*[^xyz]/)#*[xyz](D.)
```

Comment: `LC_ALL=C find . -regex '.*[^xyz]/[^/]*[xyz]' -type f` shows `./xyz/abc/xyz`

Comment: Well, direct parent, right. And what about indirect parents?

Comment: @tomas, see the rest of the answer. If you just want to skip the `*[xyz]` directories, then that's just `-prune` you need like in the `find . -name '*[xyz]' -prune -type f` solution I gave.

Comment: Looks ok. I'll use it in my answer, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1

For only files in **all** subdirectories, at any depth:

(after Stéphane Chazelas)

```
 find . -name '*[xyz]' -prune -type f
```

#### 2

For only files in subdirectories at depth 2, try this:

(Includes non-standard options. I'm not that good yet to omit them with untrivial understanding. For details, see the comments.)

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth '2' -wholename "./*[^xyz]/*[xyz]" -type f 2>/dev/null
```

`find` looks for files

`.` tells find to start in the current directory

`-mindepth 2` means the search should begin 1 level deeper than the current directory

`-maxdepth 2` means the search should end 1 level deeper than the current directory

`-wholename` defines the file path value `./*[^xyz]/*[xyz]` is what you defined in your question

`-type f` tells find to look for files only

`2>/dev/null` tells find not to print error messages

#### 3

If you want not only files but direcories too, this is easier:

```
ls -d *[^xyz]/*[xyz]
```

`ls` is for listing files and directories

`ls -d` is `ls` with option `-d` which doesn't show what's in directories

#### UPDATE

> i am just curious as to how you change the search criteria to the end
>   of the file name instead of including the file extension. So the
>   search would show file**z**.abc instead of file.ab**z**

This gives a listing in the current dir:

```
ls -d *[xyz].???
```

In Linux files don't have extensions as you imagine them. The extension is a part of the file name. Rewriting all previous commands is a bit complicated, especially the first one.

1.

(The best I've come up with so far.)

```
find . -path '.*[^xyz]/*[xyz].???' -type f | grep -v [xyz]/
```

2.

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth '2' -wholename "./*[^xyz]/*[xyz].???" -type f 2>/dev/null
```

3.

```
ls -d *[^xyz]/*[xyz].???
```

Comment: seems like it works tomas, what would the code change to if the question changed to "List all files **names (so this excludes the file extension)** that end in a set of characters, but not in sub directories"

Comment: File and file name is the same thing on Linux. So to say. What's the question anyway? I'm now working on point 1 in my answer. Make up your mind what you want and edit your question accordingly please.

Comment: He deleted his comment, i am just curious as to how you change the search criteria to the end of the file name instead of including the file extension. So the search would show file**z**.abc instead of file.ab**z**

Comment: The standard equivalent is `ls -d -- *[!xyz]/*[xyz]`. A difference with the `find` version is that it will look inside symlinks to directories.

Comment: The portable/standard equivalent of `-wholename` is `-path`. `-mindepth`/`-maxdepth` are not standard. See also `-depth 2` with FreeBSD `find`.

Comment: @SpdTolas See the update to my answer for your extra question. 1 is difficult, so most likely Stephene Chazelas will provide this one soon.